# Java/Swing: How to correctly using FlowLayout to add multiple JPanels on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, flowlayout

I want to add two JPanels in a JFrame, I tryied this:

```
JPanel container;
JPanel jp;
JPanel jp2;
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
container.setLayout(layout);
jp = new Drawing();
jp2= new Drawing2();
container.add(jp);
container.add(jp2);
setContentPane(container)
setVisible(true);
```

container.setLayout gives me

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Can you help me please? Thanks you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: you do not have to manually setContentPane for a jPanel

Comment: In every tutorial they use directly `new FlowLayout()` or `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)` and they haven't this exception. I try with `new FlowLayout(0)` and still have the exception...

Comment: You never instantiated `container`. Also, why not just set the FlowLayout as the layout manager of the existing content pane of the frame, instead of creating a new one?